# React sliding sidebar that changes the sites url

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a site using **React.js** which when you click on the link to find more info, a sidebar appears with the additional information.  The problem that I am having is that when the sidebar appears, **I want the url to change as well.** It is similar to a sliding page transition but the sliding page is a sidebar instead that only covers half the page. I hope that makes sense. **Any help in which direction I can go in to investigate if this is possible will be a great help!**

[Website page navigation layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXu0a.jpg)

Comment: I just googled "react change url" and there's tons of relevant links on the first page. Please always do basic research before posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the url I suspect using [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter) will be your best bet. You can get access to history and push in the url you want. Cool design, man.

You'd want to push in the new url in the history on click of the link btw. Also as I can see by the first comment that showed up always try googling first cause people are assholes on this site and will just shit on you for not googling this since it is pretty common to use the history and change the url.

Good luck!